# UART/I2C Pull up resistors

Tags: i2c, uart, pullup

I have question regarding the pull-up resistors when UART/I2C lines are running on 2.5V and GND. Is it OK if pull up resistors are used on these lines which are connected to 3.3V 
or Vice versa when bus is on 3.3V and pull-ups are connected to 2.5V.

Comment: UART doesn't usually need a pullup, infact it usually idles low, so if anything it would be a pull down (most micros will let you invert UART to be the other way around though). I2C does need pull ups and the calculation for resistor values can be  found on google. I would keep the digital high/low voltages all the same is there a reason that you cannot do this?

Answer (score 1):

Bus on 2.5V, pulling up to 3.3V:
It depends on the IC's communicating this bus. When their SDA/SDC input voltages are allowed to become 3.3V, you can pull the lines up to 3.3V. (e.g. some 3.3V uP allow for even 5V input signals). (Do check max input voltage level as well as max input current.)

Bus on 3.3V, pulling up to 2.5V:
Check again the datasheets of the IC's communicating this bus how their logic levels are defined.

Answer (score 0):

The [I<sup>2</sup>C standard](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf) defines the \$V_{IH}\$ as \$0.7 \times V_{DD}\$, so on a 3.3 V MCU you should reach 2.31 V in a "certain time". Depending on the bus capacitance and speed, this can be impractical.

<sub>*(Note: Some legacy I<sup>2</sup>C devices use \$V_{IH}\$ = 3.0 V, but all new devices require the 70 % specification.)*</sub>